# WPF controls, saving real estate

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm pretty new to WPF and C# and am trying to help out on some GUI stuff for work.  We basically have 3 sections, a LHS (left hand side) [section 1], a RHS that has a top and bottom section [section 2 and section 3].  Looks like this

```
1 | 2
1 | -
1 | 3
```

They want a way to shrink each section with a button click.  Currently the | and - are spacer items and can be dragged (Edit: this is done using a gridsplitter which they don't like).  I did a little research and saw there are expander items and accordion items.  I didn't know if either could be used for this scenario, and what would be the least hassle.  In trying each just a bit, some additional questions for the controls come to mind since I'm not familiar with them.

Expander:
By shrinking section 1, would it make section 2 and 3 then take up the whole screen?  Or can this only be done with an Accordion?
Is it hard/easy to change the <> icons to +- icons?  If so, any tutorial out there?

Accordion:
Can the <> be changed to +-?  If so, any tutorial out there?
Can the default color of blue be changed?

TIA

Comment: What about the grid splitter do they not like? the appearance or behavior?

Comment: @townsean: they don't like the behavior.  They prefer the click method.  Annoying I know.

Comment: Regarding the scaling issues, one way to get the scaling behavior you're after is to use nested DockPanel controls.  Alternately, you can use a Grid with properly selected "Auto" and "*" Rows/Columns.  Any rows/columns you wish to collapse with an expander should have "Auto" for their height/width.

Comment: ah yeah, that's good to bring up.

Comment: Regarding your question on the Expander, I don't think the expander would work because I believe it only shrinks and expands vertically.  In your scenario for panel 1, you would need it to expand and collapse horizontally.

Comment: No there's a property you use to change expand direction: Expander.ExpandDirection

Answer (score 2):

An `Expander` sounds like a suitable option for your situation. Fortunately it's included with WPF out of the box, unlike the Accordion control.  But I found this question related to the [Accordion control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485232/is-there-a-wpf-control-i-can-use-to-expand-collapse-panels-animated) and thought it'd be useful for you to check out.

To change the appearance of the `Expander` toggle button you'll want to modify its [control template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753296.aspx).  Changing the template to display plus or minus instead of arrows isn't too tough. If you visit the link you'll see you're going to want to change `ExpanderToggleButton` portion of the template.

Since you just want to change from using the arrows to using plus/minus signs you can simply change the `Path` data for collasped/expanded arrow.  You can look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747393.aspx) for more infortmation on drawing simple shapes with path.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250788/how-to-modify-expander-button-background-only-wpf) is an example of someone modifying the control template of the `Expander`. It's for a different tweek in appearance, but it should be useful should you decide to go this route.

***EDIT:***

Really simple example (without the change in ToggleButton appearance) to get an idea of how to collaspe and save real estate:

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
       <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
   </Grid.ColunmDefinitions>
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
       <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
       <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <Expander Name="Section1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Colunm="0" ExpandDirection="Left">
       <!-- Stuff goes here -->
   </Expander>
   <Expander Name="Section2" Grid.RowSpan="0" Grid.Colunm="1" 
       <!-- Stuff goes here -->
   </Expander>
   <Expander Name="Section3" Grid.RowSpan="1" Grid.Colunm="0" 
       <!-- Stuff goes here -->
   </Expander>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use GridSplitter.  The user can drag them to change the size.  Not a click - a drag.

```
   <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" 
                  Width="3" Background="Purple" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Center" ShowsPreview="False" >
```

Comment: Yeah we have a gridsplitter in there now and they don't like it.  I made that mroe clear now in my question.

Comment: What don't they like about the the GridSplitter?  What is the difference between a user and a terrorist?  You can reason with a terrorist.

Comment: 'Minimizing' vs. 'Splitting' is a very common distinction and this metaphor is used throughput many UIs.  Users like being able to 'Roll Up' or 'Hide' a panel area when it has functions that they occassionally need, but don't need visbility of at all times.  Grid Splitters are more suited to when you need to provide parallel views of information.  The right solution in this case might actually be a combination (a re-sizable boundary, but with a way to 'collapse' a panel.)  This is similar to what Visual Studio provides (along with other Window docking features.)

Comment: Had a couple cases where I switched out a splitter for an expander.  It is a cool tool for managing screen real estate.