# How to Display Items and Details with Windows Explorer Expand/Collapse

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0, controls

I have some items that I want to show to the user in a WPF window, but I want to hide the details of each item until the user selects/expands the item. I'd like to achieve Windows-Explorer-esque functionality, where the item Header is always displayed, and the item Details (as an `ItemsControl`) are displayed when the user clicks on the item's arrow.

*Is there an obvious way to do this?* Or am I going to have to whip out a custom control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with the standard WPF Treeview.  Josh Smith's article on [Simplifying the WPF TreeView](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode) includes a sample showing how to provide lazy-loading of the data for the subitems within each `TreeViewItem`.

The basic approach is to make a "dummy" child of each item in the `ViewModel`, and track the expanded state of each `TreeViewItem`.  As a `TreeViewItem` is expanded, the dummy child is removed and replaced with the real data.

Comment: Thank you, that is the appearance I want. The children, however, are actually `TreeViewItem`, which means they are individually selectable. How do I get the entire package - parent and details - to be one selectable unit?

Comment: @Joseph You can make them non-hierarchical, and just use a ListView instead of a TreeView, in that case.  Each ListView can just be handled via an expander, and fill in it's children..

Comment: Yeah, I would rather it look/function like the `TreeView` (click on little arrow to expand Details), but I might be just being picky. It's unfortunate that `Expander` is so difficult to [customize](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/250788/how-to-modify-expander-button-background-only-wpf).

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to automatically expand/collapse items then you probably want a trigger. For example you can use an expander and automatically Expand it when the mouse is over it.

```
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

And of course this can be repeated for other triggers that you want to set it to be open

```
        <Expander Header="Hello" IsExpanded="False">
            <Border Background="Red" Height="32"/>
            <Expander.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Expander">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Expander">
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"/>
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="expander" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                        <Setter TargetName="expander" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>                                
                </Style>
            </Expander.Style>
        </Expander>
```

If you don't need a full tree like UI then it would probably be sufficient to just have a list of these, but I'm pretty sure you can also use the same trick on a treeviewitem too.

Comment: Apologies this is a really poor example and not making any use of the expander, but it does show the trigger idea. I'll update in the morning to something a little better.

Comment: This is a really neat idea, but it might throw the user off if the items are, for example, stacked vertically and the expand/collapse feature is also vertical. If they're trying to move down the list, it would be pretty easy to expand many items they didn't want to.

Comment: Actually, since the mouse can only ever be over one control at a time, you'll end up with the same action as the AJAX accordion control. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I took the `ListBox` of `Expander`s path, and I am pretty pleased with the results.

Here's how my final code ended up:

**Control Template for Expander Button**

```
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="TreeViewToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Border x:Name="ToggleButtonBorder"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                    Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                <Grid>
                    <Rectangle Fill="Transparent"/>

                    <Path x:Name="Arrow"
                          Height="10" Width="10"
                          Stroke="Black"
                          Data="m 2 1 v 8 l 4 -3.75 Z">
                    </Path>
                </Grid>
            </Border>

            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Data" Value="m 2 9 h 5 v -5 Z"/>
                    <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Fill" Value="Black"/>
                </Trigger>

                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Stroke" Value="#00A7C2"/>
                </Trigger>

                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                        <Condition Property="IsChecked" Value="True"/>
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>

                    <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Fill" Value="#00A7C2"/>
                </MultiTrigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
```

**Control Template for Expander**

```
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="TreeViewExpander" TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
            <DockPanel>
                <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <ToggleButton x:Name="ExpanderButton"
                                  Grid.Column="0"
                                  Template="{StaticResource TreeViewToggleButton}"
                                  IsChecked="{Binding IsExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                  OverridesDefaultStyle="True"
                                  Padding="2, 0" />
                    <Label Grid.Column="1" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                           Padding="0, 1"/>
                </Grid>

                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ExpanderContent"
                                  Visibility="Collapsed"
                                  DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"/>
            </DockPanel>

            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="ExpanderContent" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
```

**Usage in Window**

```
    <ListBox Grid.Row="1" DataContext="{Binding Inputs}" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False">
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Expander Template="{StaticResource TreeViewExpander}"
                                      IsExpanded="{Binding IsExpanded}">
                                <Expander.Header>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Timestamp, StringFormat=Time: {0}}"/>
                                </Expander.Header>
                                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Variables}" Margin="30 0 0 0"/>
                            </Expander>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>

                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListBox>
```